# how to convert binary value to hex decimal in erlang

Tags: erlang

I am getting binary value like `<<"0421">>` and this hex representation of `0x0421`.
and I have to get the bit values of this hex value.
and in 2'base representation would be this is `0000 0100 0010 0001`.

So I need to get each bit of this hex in Erlang.

If I use `list_to_integer(binary_to_list())` I get 421 in integer.

Please help me to convert this binary to hex first and then get the bit value of those hex.

Comment: `binary_to_integer(<<"0421">>, 16)`?

Comment: Thanks @Dogbert, I am bit new to erlang.  When I got the value 1057 and its integer and now each bit represent something. from bit0 to bit15. how I can get each bit now.

Comment: I've added that to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Dogbert ...I needed exactly that. I was not getting how to get 4 zeros padded at start.

Answer (score 3):

`binary_to_integer/2` accepts a base as the second argument. You can pass `16` to it to convert a hex binary to integer:

```
1> binary_to_integer(<<"0421">>, 16).
1057
2> 16#0421.
1057
```

Edit: You can extract each of the 16 bits into 16 variables using pattern matching:

```
1> Integer = binary_to_integer(<<"0421">>, 16).
1057
2> <<B0:1, B1:1, B2:1, B3:1, B4:1, B5:1, B6:1, B7:1, B8:1, B9:1, B10:1, B11:1, B12:1, B13:1, B14:1, B15:1>> = <<Integer:16>>.
<<4,33>>
3> {B0, B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7, B8, B9, B10, B11, B12, B13, B14, B15}.
{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1}
```

`B0` is now `0`, `B5` is `1`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
1> integer_to_list(binary_to_integer(<<"0421">>, 16),2).
"10000100001"
```

See the documentation for the same core [`erlang`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html) module. Especially pay attention to the second parameter of [`integer_to_list/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#integer_to_list-2).

Comment: Thanks for providing code which might help solving the problem, but generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem.

Comment: @LordWilmore: Although you a right that explanation for a solution would generally be better than just providing just solution but here I use functions from module `erlang` which is the most basic module in Erlang environment. It would be like explaining the meaning of `+` which is actually `erlang:'+'/2` function from the same module. I can add RTFM as an explanation but I would consider it rude.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say much about the expected format of the result, based on Dogbert proposal, here is a more automated solution.

```
1> HexToBin = fun(D) -> 
1> S = size(D) * 4,
1> I = binary_to_integer(D,16),
1> << << X >> || <<X:1>> <= << I:S >> >> 
1> end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.52032458>
2> HexToBin(<<"0421">>). 
<<0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1>>
3> rp(HexToBin(<<"00123456789abcdef0421">>)).
<<0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,
  0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,
  1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1>>
ok
4>
```

Answer (score -1):

Dogbert's solution might get a little tedious with big integers.

```
bits(HexBin) ->
    bits(
      binary:encode_unsigned(
        binary_to_integer(HexBin, 16)
      ),
      []
    ).

bits(<<Bit:1, Rest/bitstring>>, Acc) ->
    bits(Rest, [Bit|Acc]);
bits(<<>>, Acc) ->
    list_to_tuple(lists:reverse(Acc)).
```

In the shell:

```
6> c(my).              
{ok,my}

7> my:bits(<<"0421">>).
{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1}

8> LongResult = my:bits(<<"FFFFFFFFFFFFFF0421">>).        
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...}

9> io:format("~p~n", [LongResult]).
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1}
ok
```